# Removing Characters in C#

Tags: c#

I am working with a note sorter machine through serial port communication. I am able to retrieve information out of it. However I am getting few unwanted characters all the settings baud rate etc are correct.

The following is an example of the resulting output:

```
--------------------------------JL206F             ID:VDE40050


2015/05/29    11:02:19      
JBatch_No.:067
JOperator ID:15
--------------------------------
         Mixed Counting
W--------------------------------Deposit Amount:             0.00
--------------------------------
denom       count          value
UVK(|????DW50D        1          50.00
JUVK(|????DW20D       1          20.00
JUVK(|????DW10ND          1          10.00
J--------------------------------
Total:          3          80.00
--------------------------------
Coin:                       0.00
--------------------------------
Balance:                    0.00
```

The above is the output I am getting I want to remove
`JUVK(|????DW` and all the characters similar to it. Is there any way I tried every code for replacing and removing it.

This is the code that i am using:

```
string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
tbData.AppendText(str);
tbData.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Would you not be better off just trying to read in the data with the correct encoding? What is `tbData`? What does your code do currently that is not expected?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're using the wrong encoding.

Instead of:

```
string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
```

You should use something else, perhaps:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data)
```

Now I'm just guessing at UTF8, but it seems possible, since most of your characters are being read fine, while only a few are displayed incorrectly. I'm guessing that UTF8 characters outside the ASCII-range are being interpreted as two or more ASCII characters, instead of a single UTF8 character.

Preferably, you should refer to the documentation for your sorter machine to find the correct character set to use, otherwise, you might have to resort to guesswork and experimentation until you find a set that seems to give you the right answers.

In any case, I would recomend that you do **NOT** simply delete the messed up characters, since they clearly have some meaning in the example text you provided.

**Update:** 
*(ref. comments below)*

It's a pity you could not get the correct text to begin with, but if you just want to remove the messed up text, and it is always the same, then a simple solution is as follows:

```
var strippedText = str.Replace("JUVK(|????DW", "");
```

This will simply replace all instance of `JUVK(|????DW` with an empty string.

Comment: I used  the statement of code that you provided however I am getting this as output now   JUVK(|����DW

Comment: Ok. You've got a few other alternatives to try too: `Encoding.Unicode`, `Encoding.UTF7`, `Encoding.UTF32`, `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`, or perhaps even `Encoding.Default`. Any changes in the result?

Comment: no LUCK. oUTPUT changed to JUVK(|ªªª‚DW. Actually it is a chinese machine and i have no documentation that is the big problem

Comment: Ok, one last thing to try: Use `Encoding.GetEncoding("GB18030")`. If it is the case that this is Chinese text, then that might return the correct text (Chinese characters?) for you. I don't know if this will work, but might be worth a try...

Comment: Nothing helped well is there a way that we can remove it as data that I need is already coming.

Comment: actually i checked that those characters are still in ascii form so I am  not able to replace it and also is it possible that we can have a data grid view rather having a text box

Comment: Any help for putting this data to a data grid. i AM NEW TO C# programming

Answer (score 0):

I think you want extract numbers from string, use **Regex**.

```
string s= Regex.Match("12 thsd$", @"\d+").Value;
```